# How do I return the day of the week with a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Edit:

The suggestions in the comments worked. But how do I return "null" if parameter is outside a given range like 1-7? Edited code below.

Code needs to return the day of the week when called. For example.
returnDay(1) //"Monday"
returnDay(2) //"Tuesday"
etc...

My code:

```js
function returnDay(day) {
    var dayOfWeek = ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday');
    for (var i = 0; i < day.length; i++) {
        dayOfWeek += day[i];
    }
    return dayOfWeek;
}

console.log(returnDay(1)) //returns full array, not 'Monday'
```

New code with new problems :( returns undefined

```js
function returnDay(day) {
    var dayOfWeek = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
    if (returnDay <= 0 && returnDay >= 8) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return dayOfWeek[day - 1];
    }
}
console.log(returnDay(0)); //returns undefined
```

Comment: It returns "Sunday" for me? https://codepen.io/Connum/pen/VwbPQZO?editors=1111

Comment: First of all, do a `console.log(dayOfWeek)` directly after you assigned the value to that variable. Notice something? Now go read up on how arrays actually work in JS.

Comment: Can you not just have the array of weekday names and then just reference them via day? So, day-1 (if day is 1) would be the first index. So Monday would return?

Comment: Hi ren, welcome to SO, `dayOfWeek` is array of days, so for return one of them you just need point to their index, `dayOfWeek[1]`. In your case you dont need to loop through array. So for return `Mondey` (first element of array) code be like this: `dayOfWeek[0]`. Because array index started from `zero`

Comment: For any other JS users that were confused as to what that syntax does: `var x = ('a', 'b', 'c')` and then `x` in devtools console evaluates as `"c"` :| Can an expert explain?

Comment: First of all, WOW! I'm kinda blown away at the responses I so quickly got from you guys. Yes, that's right, was some typo errors on my part. The original did return "Sunday" for me as well. Sorry about that. ...working on all of your suggestions. Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 1):

**1)** `dayOfWeek` should be an array, not comma-separated values. If you use comma-separated values and assign it to a variable then the last value gets assigned to it. i.e `Sunday` in this case.

**2)** As `dayOfWeek` is an array so you can use `index` to get the value

```
return dayOfWeek[day - 1];
```

```js
function returnDay(day) {
  var dayOfWeek = [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
    "Sunday",
  ];

  return dayOfWeek[day - 1];
}

console.log(returnDay(1)); //returns full array, not 'Monday'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function returnDay(day) {
    var dayOfWeek = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    
    return dayOfWeek[day-1];
}

returnDay(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a function, it's far easier just to reference the array when you need it. Remember arrays are zero based so Monday will be `daysOfWeek[0]`

```js
let daysOfWeek = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
console.log(`Someone's got a case of the ${daysOfWeek[0]}s`)
console.log(`${daysOfWeek[6]} Driver!`)

let randomDay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)
console.log(`It's a beautiful ${daysOfWeek[randomDay]} afternoon isn't it!`);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code given below will solve your problem. It will return null if a number is entered outside the range of 1 - 7.

```
function returnDay(num) {
    const days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]; 
    if (num < 1 || num > 7) {
        return null;

    } else {
        return days[num - 1]
    }
 }

 console.log(returnDay(8));

 console.log(returnDay(-50));
```